# I am trying to find number of non na observations in each dataframe for multiple files

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple csv files in a folder which consists of data of PM values of sulfate and nitrate. The dataframe has NA values and I am trying to find how many observations are complete, i.e. each row has no NA values. I tried using the !is.na() on the dataframe and adding it up but it gave me how many values are non NA values.

This is the code -

```
complete<-function(directory,id=1:332)
{
   temp<-list.files(pattern='*.csv')
   myfiles<-do.call(rbind, lapply(temp, function(x) read.csv(x)))
   v<-numeric(length(id))
   k<-1
   for(j in id)
   {
      m<-myfiles[myfiles$ID==j,]
      v[k]<-sum(!is.na(m))
      k<-k+1
   }
   result<-data.frame(id,nobs=v)
   return(result)
}
```

The directory is the folder containing the CSV files.
In the R studio, I have set the directory as the working directory.

Comment: Look into `complete.cases()`.

Comment: you want to use the `complete.cases( )` function to get only rows with no `NA`'s

Answer (score 0):

This should get how many rows of a single dataframe have one or more NA values inside:

```
sum(rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0)
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I got it using `complete.cases()`

Comment: event better :)